Vuex and Vue Router - double condition on beforeEnter not working
I have double condition in beforeEnter and nobody can enter to right place. Is there a limit in conditions or what? :(
my code in the router file:
const routes = {
    path: `${routerConfig.preRoute}/absence`,
    beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
        storeInit
            .then(() => {
                const admin = store.getters.userIsAdmin;
                const userHasPermission = store.getters.userIsAbsencesAdmin;
                if (!admin || !userHasPermission) {
                    next('/');
                }
                else next();
            });
    },

my code in the store file:
getters: {
        userIsAdmin: (state, getters) => {
            return state.userPermissions.some(permission => +permission === permissionsArray.ADMIN_PLATFORM);
        },
        userIsGoalAdmin: (state, getters) => {
            return state.userPermissions.some(permission => +permission === permissionsArray.ADMIN_GOAL);
        },
        userIsAbsencesAdmin: (state, getters) => {
            // return state.userPermissions.some(permission => +permission === permissionsArray.ADMIN_ABSENCES || +permission === permissionsArray.ADMIN_PLATFORM);
            return state.userPermissions.some(permission => +permission === permissionsArray.ADMIN_ABSENCES);
        },
        user: (state, getters) => {
            return state.user;
        },
    },

I need admin or userHasPermission enter to next(), but everyone is redirected to next('/').
Everything works fine when the condition is either !admin or !userHasPermission. The problem is in a double condition with ||.

There's no such limit. You can debug what admin and userHasPermission values are, this will explain it. Currently the question lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and only you can do this

your conditional logic is backwards. you want people with permission or admins to be routed normally, which means you want people without permission AND who are not admins to be redirected. this can be written as !admin && !userHasPermission though personally I would restructure this to be have admin || userHasPermission let the user through and use the else block to redirect

Try to use async method
beforeEnter: async (to, from, next) => {
    await storeInit
        .then(() => {
            const admin = store.getters.userIsAdmin;
            const userHasPermission = store.getters.userIsAbsencesAdmin;
            if (!admin || !userHasPermission) {
                next('/');
            }
            else next();
        });
},

